# append an ID to the last div inside the div

Tags: jquery

could somebody help me with following? I'm new to jquery and your help will be really appreciated. I need to append an ID to the last children of div.cenik if the width of window is less than 768 px? Thanks for your help.

```
<div class="cenik">
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div> <-- this should get the ID-->
</div>
```

my code (something is wrong):

```
 (function($) {$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($(window).width() < 768) {
   $('.cenik').children().last(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'cenik');
});
 }
 });})( jQuery );
```

Comment: It sounds like a XY problem, why would you need to add an ID to this DIV?

Comment: @A.Wolff, maybe he has a style in css targeting that id?

Comment: @AmmarCSE But then he should use CSS media queries i guess. It really depends what is the purpose of using an ID here

Comment: It's because of an anchor link, when I'm at small screen I need to hide some parts and refer to another. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.cenik').children().last().attr('id', 'cenik');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

That's said, there it is how it should be done, i guess:

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
            $('.cenik').children().last().attr('id', 'cenik');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

this must be your solution

html

```
<div class="cenik">
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div>
  <div>bla bla</div> <-- this should get the ID-->
</div>
```

jquery

```
 (function($) {$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($(window).width() < 768) {
     $('.cenik > div:last').attr("id","cenik")
};
 }
)})( jQuery );
```

live : 
https://jsfiddle.net/23kbt25s/

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass a callback function

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                $('.cenik').children().last().attr('id', 'cenik');
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

**Or**, you can use [**:last**](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.cenik div:last').attr('id', 'cenik');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```